# Eclipse can't determine node.js version

Tags: node.js, eclipse

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMj55.png)

When I use Eclipse to build a maven project. I need SpringBoot so now I want to edit .yml file. But it always pops this interface! I have tried version 10、12. Now the node.js version is v10.20.1. I have edit the .bash_profile and export /usr/local/bin. Should I make some changes in Eclipse?

Comment: As far as I know (I'm not a macOS user), you have to add it to the `PATH` environment variable instead of adding it to `.bash_profile`. What do you mean exactly by _"export /usr/local/bin"_?

Comment: When I add system level environment variable, I will use "vim ./.bash_profile" then edit this file. i'm sorry i did't discribe the problem so well. i add "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/" in this file.

Comment: And the node.js executable is in `/usr/local/bin/`? `.bash_profile` does not matter here.

Comment: When I install node.js, it says that be sure to make `/usr/local/bin/` in the PATH. So I think the path is right. And if I tab `node -v` in the terminal i can get the certain version.

Comment: I see. Which Eclipse (and STS?) version do you have? As a workaround, right-click the file and choose _Open With > Text Editor_.